# is there some standard or recommended way to sort HTML and component properties in svelte?

Tags: svelte

Moreover, I'd like to know how can it affect the running code changing the sort of props.

(I think I once had problems putting the `bind:value` after a `on:change` event, but I can't quite recall the issue)

Looking at the svelte tutorial, it seems something like that is (not strictly) followed:

```html
<input
  name="scoops"
  placeholder={holder}
  type="text" // regular props first

  class="bg-red" // style props
  style="background: {color}"

  bind:value // bound values
  bind:group={scoops}

  on:click={() => selected = color} // events
  on:change={(e) => store.mark(todo, e.currentTarget.checked)}

  in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 2000 }} // animations
  out:fade

  use:tooltip={{ content, theme: 'material' }} // use actions last
/>
```

But I'm just guessing.

Is there some recommended order and how can the order of props affect the running code?

---

Update: I found the reference about how the order of properties might affect the result:

see https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-property

[image]